# Using jspdf.debug.js Wrap table head in pdf when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am using jspdf.debug.js for generation html table in pdf format.
The table heading is not wrapping properly, shown like this: 
[image of the distorted heading jspdf.debug.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLds.png)

below is the code that prints out the thead. though it doesn't wrap long text in next line

```
 jsPDFAPI.printHeaderRow = function (lineNumber, new_page) {

    if (!this.tableHeaderRow) {
        throw 'Property tableHeaderRow does not exist.';
    }

    var tableHeaderCell,
        tmpArray,
        i,
        ln;

    this.printingHeaderRow = true;
    if (headerFunction !== undefined) {
        var position = headerFunction(this, pages);
        setLastCellPosition(position[0], position[1], position[2], position[3], -1);
    }
    this.setFontStyle('bold');
    var tempHeaderConf = [];
    for (i = 0, ln = this.tableHeaderRow.length; i < ln; i += 1) {
        this.setFillColor(248,218,194);

        //this.maxWidth(10);
        //this.setWidth(10);
        // console.log("width"+this.width);
        /*changed neeraj color of table heading*/
        //this.setFillColor(200,200,200);


        tableHeaderCell = this.tableHeaderRow[i];
        if (new_page) {
            tableHeaderCell[1] = this.margins && this.margins.top || 0;
            tempHeaderConf.push(tableHeaderCell);
        }
        tmpArray = [].concat(tableHeaderCell);
        this.cell.apply(this, tmpArray.concat(lineNumber));
    }
    if (tempHeaderConf.length > 0){
        this.setTableHeaderRow(tempHeaderConf);
    }
    this.setFontStyle('normal');
    this.printingHeaderRow = false;
};
})(jsPDF.API);
```

code for the same if fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/afas07Lf/

Answer (score 3):

I am using jsPDF version 1.0.272

In `jsPDFAPI.table = function (x,y, data, headers, config)` (Around line 2833)

1. after      `if (printHeaders) {` 
   clause, I added `true` as the last parameter to the call to calculateLineHeight():
   `var lineHeight = this.calculateLineHeight(headerNames, columnWidths, headerPrompts.length?headerPrompts:headerNames,true);`
2. Next, in the for loop, I removed the String() from the last parameter:
   `tableHeaderConfigs.push([x, y, columnWidths[header], lineHeight, (headerPrompts.length ? headerPrompts[i] : header)]);`
3. In the for loop after the `//Construct the data rows` comment, I added false as the last parameter to calculateLineHeight():
   `lineHeight = this.calculateLineHeight(headerNames, columnWidths, model,false);`
4. I added another parameter, isHeader, to the calculateLineHeight function:
   `jsPDFAPI.calculateLineHeight = function (headerNames, columnWidths, model, isHeader)`
5. Then I modified the function:

`jsPDFAPI.calculateLineHeight = function (headerNames, columnWidths, model, isHeader) {
        var header, lineHeight = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < headerNames.length; j++) {
            header = headerNames[j];
            if(isHeader){
                model[j] = this.splitTextToSize(String(model[j]),    columnWidths[model[j].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')] - padding);
                var h = this.internal.getLineHeight() * model[j].length + padding;
            }else{
                model[header] = this.splitTextToSize(String(model[header]), columnWidths[header] - padding);
                var h = this.internal.getLineHeight() * model[header].length + padding;
            }
        if (h > lineHeight)
                lineHeight = h;
        }
        return lineHeight;
    };`

And if you want to unbold the table headings, go to function
`jsPDFAPI.printHeaderRow = function (lineNumber, new_page)` and comment the line `this.setFontStyle('bold');`